# How to pass parameter to eloquent model class to get custom relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following model in Laravel

```
class Card extends Model
{
    public $forAgentId;

    protected $with = [
        'agent_special_price',
    ];

    public function agent_special_price()
    {
        if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) {
            if ($this->forAgentId) {
                // Get special price for agent with id=$forAgentId
                return $this->belongsTo(AgentSpecialPrice::class, 'id', 'card_id')->where('user_id', $this->attributes['forAgentId']);
            } else {
                // Get all special prices
                return $this->belongsTo(AgentSpecialPrice::class, 'id', 'card_id');
            }
        }
        // User is agent
        return $this->belongsTo(AgentSpecialPrice::class, 'id', 'card_id')->where('user_id', Auth::id());
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve using this code is to get the `agent special price` from another table to a specific `card`.

I'm trying to get the `agent special price` based on different conditions. One of those conditions is to get the prices based on `$forAgentId`.

In my controller, I wrote the following code to get the `agent special price` for a specific `$forAgentId`:

```
<?php
public function getAllForAdminWithAgentData($agentId)
{
    $card = new Card();
    $card->forAgentId = $agentId;
    return response()->success(
        QueryBuilder::for(Card::setModel($card))
            ->allowedFilters(
                'name',
                AllowedFilter::trashed()
            )->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10)
    );
}
```

But the code above `getAllForAdminWithAgentData` doesn't work when I run it and I have the role `admin`. What I expect from the `getAllForAdminWithAgentData` method is to execute the relation and get all `agent_special_price` for agent with `id=$agentId` only, but the code gets the `agent_special_price` for all users.

How can I modify `getAllForAdminWithAgentData` method such that it will change the `forAgentId` variable in the `Card` class and execute the `agent_special_price` relation after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setModel()` does not do what you appear to want.

A new query builder instance is being created with the `Card` subject, and when you are looking for `$this->forAgentId`, it is looking for an attribute or database column named `forAgentId`, which does not exist.

I would remove the property `forAgentId` in the `Card` class, and just use:

```php
        QueryBuilder::for(Card::class)
            ->allowedFilters(
                'name',
                AllowedFilter::trashed()
            )
            ->orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->paginate(10)
```

and then one option would be to update the eager loading definition,

```php
            if ($this->forAgentId) {
```

changing `$this->forAgentId` to however you get the agent ID in the first place, e.g. from the request or the session.

Or constrain the relation in the builder:

```php
        QueryBuilder::for(Card::class)
            ->with(['agent_special_price' => fn ($query) => $query->where(....)])
            ....
```